# Reloading individual iFrame on slideChange

Tags: jquery, iframe, slider, reload, swiper.js

I'm coding an interactive exhibit for my school's graduation showcase.

I'm using Swiper Slider and I placed embedded SoundCloud iFrames in each slide. I would like that once user has listened to an audio and move to the next slider, the previous embedded audio has its iFrame reloaded.

Right now I can't access SoundCloud's API, so that's a definite no go.

What I have right now works, but instead of reloading the iFrame of the previous slider on `slideChange`, it can only target specific iFrames.

Thus I targeted all iFrames in case the next user of the exhibit comes and realised that all audio have been played and there is no way to for user to restart unless seeking manually (which is bad UX). What I did is:

```
var reload1 = $("#reload1");
var reload2 = $("#reload2");
var reload3 = $("#reload3");
var reload4 = $("#reload4");
var reload5 = $("#reload5");

swiper.on("slideChange", function() {
  reload1.attr("src", function(i, val) {return val;});
  reload2.attr("src", function(i, val) {return val;});
  reload3.attr("src", function(i, val) {return val;});
  reload4.attr("src", function(i, val) {return val;});
  reload5.attr("src", function(i, val) {return val;});
});
```

I'm sorry if it looks really sloppy and basic, I have only learned JavaScript on a basic level.

Here's the CodePen: https://codepen.io/aahlfeeyann/pen/aYyevp

I would appreciate it if anyone has any suggestion or solution for this, thanks!

Comment: Posted the answer hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any pretty sliders or carousel has `index` calling methods or properties. So basically you need the same here.

## How to load only the previous slides iframe?

- On slide change, **get the previous index**.
- Get the previous frames `id` and use the index with `id` to reset src of previous iframe.

## This is what you want:

**JS updates:**

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  effect: "coverflow",
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",

  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 0,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 350,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: false
  }
});

swiper.on("slideChange", function() {
  console.log(" Prev slide was: " + swiper.previousIndex);
  var prevSlide = swiper.previousIndex;
  //Setting up index as per id's of iframe
  prevSlide = prevSlide + 1;
  var targetFrame = $("iframe[id='reload" + prevSlide + "']");
  $(targetFrame).attr("src", $(targetFrame).attr("src"));
});
```

> Codepen [link](https://codepen.io/divy3993/pen/pLrMOb) to play around.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: That's a perfect answer, exactly what I'm looking for. Surprised I didn't see the previousIndex method. 

I understand the logic behind what you did, but to aid with my understanding even more, what does 

    ```prevSlide = prevSlide + 1;
    var targetFrame = $("iframe[id='reload" + prevSlide + "']");

    ```
means? And what does it do? Thanks!

Comment: Ah I see. Now I get it. It's because I set the IDs as #reload1, #reload2, .... and since the previousIndex starts at 0, adding a +1 fits exactly with the ID of the previous Index. Now I get it. That's amazing, thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped you.